# Target and independent variables in random forest

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, random-forest

I want to analyse the "[House Sales in King County](https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction)" with a random forest algorithm. So far, I managed to load the data, prepare the data - but I struggle to select the right target and independent variable.

My goal is to select all the variables from the dataset as input variables and the target variable should be the price.

My code (see below) is somehow working right now, but not even close to my goal (predicting prices through different variables). I tried several different approaches - but everything ended in an error (like: Number of labels=17 does not match number of samples=15128).

It would be great if someone could help me with this problem :-)

```
# Load Libraries
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

dataset= pd.read_csv('kc_house_data.csv')

dataset = dataset.drop('id', axis=1)
dataset = dataset.drop('date', axis=1)
dataset = dataset.drop('zipcode', axis=1)
dataset = dataset.drop('long', axis=1)

cols = ['price', 'bathrooms', 'floors', 'bedrooms', 'sqft_living', 'sqft_lot', 'waterfront', 'view', 'condition', 'grade', 'lat', 'sqft_above']
dataset[cols] = dataset[cols].applymap(np.int64)

print(dataset.shape)
print(dataset.dtypes)

# Splitting Dataset
Train,Test = train_test_split(dataset, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 176)

Train_IndepentVars = Train.values[:, 3:5]
Train_TargetVar = Train.values[:,5]
Test_IndepentVars = Test.values[:, 3:5]
Test_TargetVar = Test.values[:,5]

##RF
main=['view', 'bedrooms', 'floors', 'grade']
rf_model =  RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=30,n_estimators=15)
rf_model.fit(Train_IndepentVars, Train_TargetVar)

predictions = rf_model.predict(Train_IndepentVars)

###Confusion Matrix

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
# Confusion Matrix
print(" Confusion matrix ", confusion_matrix(Train_TargetVar, predictions))

importance =  rf_model.feature_importances_
importance = pd.DataFrame(importance, index=Train.columns[3:5], 
                          columns=["Importance"])

print(importance)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of the number of estimators being quite low. Try using more estimators. Atleast more than 100 or something. Apart from that, even though random forests are used for regression, it's not really a good technique because it will average the results out from the trees and would have specific levels in which it would give results, like buckets. You could try linear regression on this kind of a dataset. 
I can also see that you are using on 3 features in your training and testing. You could rather use all of them, or at least most of them.

Random forest is still a good technique, please try increasing the number of estimators. You could also try making some new features out of the existing data for e.g. total area of the house but adding all the sq.ft. columns.

```
train_cols = ['bathrooms', 'floors', 'bedrooms', 'sqft_living', 'sqft_lot', 'waterfront', 'view', 'condition', 'grade', 'lat', 'sqft_above']
label = 'price'
X_train = train.ix[:, train_cols]
X_test = test.ix[: train_cols]
y_train = train.ix[:, label]
y_test = test.ix[:, label]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you mean with "number of estimators"? That's exactly the point - i want to use more than 3 features - but I don't know how in terms of code.

Comment: Thanks for the code!!! Unfortunately, it gets me: TypeError: '['bathrooms', 'floors', 'bedrooms', 'sqft_living', 'sqft_lot', 'waterfront', 'view', 'condition', 'grade', 'lat', 'sqft_above']' is an invalid key.

Comment: I showed that as an example to how to include or exclude columns. See your dataframe, think of what columns you want to train on, and put them in a list. Filter the dataframe as I've showed and if you want only values then just train.ix[:, train_cols].values